I have to FIND three consecutive triangular numbers whose product is a perfect square.
[DUPLICATE]
So, a user had posted this exact question.
When is the product of $3$ consecutive triangular numbers a perfect square
My try:
$k^2 = n(n+1)^2(n+2)^2\frac{n+3}{  8}$ where $n$ and $k$ are integers, then
$\frac{n(n+3)}{2}$ must be a square number
$n(n+3) =2x^2$ , $n^2+3n-2x^2=0$
then the discriminant must also be a perfect square.
$9+8x^2 = y^2$ but I don't know how to solve this in integers.
None of the answers provided a way to actually solve this. I mean how do I solve pell type equations? I don't know anything about continued fractions, do I need to learn it all? I'm simply breezing through number theory.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
